# How to best add an UPSELL (add-on) checkout step to Magento ver 1.9.2.1?

Tags: checkout, up-sells, upselling

What is the best way to add a new check-out step which would just have my up-sell products? I would like it to work like proflowers.com has it (please see the screenshot)

Thanks for any suggestions! :-*

[image]

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/17859/adding-a-step-to-the-one-page-checkout